# Python TKInter how do I replace data in my frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a major issue with my code below. So here's what I'm trying to do.

The user enters certain inputs into the entry fields and the program calculates and displays a corresponding image (loaded in the frame `champFrame`) and it's description (in `spellFrame`).

What I want is to replace this image and text every time I click on the `Calculate!` button so that it shows me a new image and new description based on my new inputs.
However, in its current state, when I enter new input and click the `Calculate!` button, it just adds the new image below the old one and the old one is still there.

How do I change my code around so that I can replace these old values?
I have heard of using the `pack_forget()` method but it only hides the previous image, does not remove it so I can replace it with a new one.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from Calculation import getHighestScore
from ImageHandler import *
import json
import urllib2

top = Tk()
top.title("LOLSpellEfficiency")
top.geometry("600x600")

def loadInputFields(frame):
    AP_Label = Label(frame, text="AP")
    AD_Label = Label(frame, text="AD")
    CDR_Label = Label(frame, text="CDR")

    AP_Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    AD_Label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    CDR_Label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    AP_Entry = Entry(frame)

    AD_Entry = Entry(frame)

    CDR_Entry = Entry(frame)

    AP_Entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    AP_Entry.insert(0, "0")
    AD_Entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    AD_Entry.insert(0, "0")
    CDR_Entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    CDR_Entry.insert(0, "0")

    return [AP_Entry, AD_Entry, CDR_Entry]


def loadButton(frame, entries):
    Enter_Button = Button(frame, text="Calculate!", command = lambda: executeProgram(entries))
    Enter_Button.pack(side=TOP)

def executeProgram(entries):

    AP = float(entries[0].get())
    AD = float(entries[1].get())
    CDR = float(entries[2].get())
    data = getChampionData()
    result = getHighestScore(data, AP, AD, CDR)

    champPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(getChampionImage(result[0]))
    champLabel = Label(championFrame, image=champPhoto)
    champLabel.image = champPhoto
    champLabel.pack(side = TOP)

    champName = Label(championFrame, text = "Champion: " + result[0])
    champName.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    spellPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(getSpellImage(result[2]))
    spellLabel = Label(spellFrame, image=spellPhoto)
    spellLabel.image = spellPhoto


    spellText = Text(spellFrame, wrap=WORD)
    spellText.insert(INSERT, "Spell: " + result[1] + "\n")
    spellText.insert(INSERT, "Spell description: " + result[3] + "\n")
    spellLabel.pack(side=TOP)
    spellText.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    championFrame.pack()
    spellFrame.pack()


def getChampionData():
    URL = "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion?champData=all&api_key=8e8904b4-c112-4b0f-bd1e-641649d9e569"
    return json.load(urllib2.urlopen(URL))


inputFrame = Frame(top)
inputFrame.pack()

buttonFrame = Frame(top)
buttonFrame.pack()

championFrame = Frame(top)
spellFrame = Frame(top)
championFrame.pack()
spellFrame.pack()

entries = loadInputFields(inputFrame)
loadButton(buttonFrame, entries)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I haven't used images in tkinter, but is `.configure()` not an option for images?

Comment: I haven't used tkinter in awhile, so this may be wrong but can't you just call label['image'] = new_image and then call top.update() to update the frame to display the changes upon clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Do not create widgets inside of `executeProgram`. Instead, create them in your main application, and simply change the widgets inside `executeProgram`.

All widgets have a `configure` method which lets you change all of the attributes of that widget. For example, to change the image on a label you would do something like this:

```
champPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(getChampionImage(result[0]))
champLabel.configure(image=champPhoto)
champLabel.image = champPhoto
```